# Make.net programs run using assemblies provided by mono

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-xp

So... Let's suppose I have a C# program that requires the .NET 4.6.1 to be installed. Once I installed it, such a program will load, looking for the required assemblies in the .NET folder provided by Microsoft. Now, let's suppose that I decide to run such a program via command line using mono (mono myprogram.exe); it would actually run using the reference assemblies provided by mono, instead of the ones provided by Microsoft. That said, my question is: is there a way to make programs use/look for assemblies provided by mono instead of the ones provided by the Microsoft automatically? I know there's no point in doing such a thing under Windows, but I actually need it for test purposes only.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Normally Fusion binding uses GAC as the first resolution source; so you could in theory remove all system assemblies from GAC and register all mono ones. The effects on the system could vary, though :)